# Flutter - Page replacement system with GetX not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a code like this:

`main.dart`:

```
body: GetX<PaginationController>(
  init: PaginationController(),
  initState: (_) {},
  builder: (controller) {
    if (controller.PageIndex.value == 0) {
      return Pages[0];
    } else if (controller.PageIndex.value == 1) {
      return Pages[1];
    } else if (controller.PageIndex.value == 2) {
      return Pages[2];
    }
  },
),
```

`PaginationController`:

```
class PaginationController extends GetxController {
  RxInt PageIndex = RxInt(0);
}
```

Coming to the question, when I press the button, I want it to switch from one of the pages in the menu to another. But it doesn't switch. In Controller the value of `PageIndex` changes but the page does not.

Menu codes:

```
PaginationController paginationController = PaginationController();
int PageIndex = paginationController.PageIndex.value;
//...
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(30),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: Colors.black38, spreadRadius: 0, blurRadius: 10),
          ],
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
          ),  
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 53, 53, 57),
            selectedFontSize: 16,
            unselectedFontSize: 13,
            selectedItemColor: Color(0xFFFBBF24),
            selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFFBBF24), fontFamily: "Inter Bold"),
            unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 192, 192, 192),
            ),
            unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Inter Regular"),
            unselectedItemColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 192, 192, 192),
            currentIndex: PageIndex,
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "Ana Sayfa",
                icon: Icon(Icons.home)
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "Sepet",
                icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket_outlined)
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "Cüzdan",
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet_rounded)
              ),
            ],
            onTap: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                PageIndex = index;
                print(PageIndex);
                print(index);
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

To change the page, I wrote the following code:

```
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      PageIndex = 2;
    });
  },
```

Menu and Body codes in one file.

The value in `PaginationController` changes but the page does not. Why could it be? How can I solve the problem? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: have you tried use? Obx or GetBuilder? to achieve this?

Comment: @ArbiterChil No, I haven't tried. Can you post it as an answer? If it works I'll mark it as a solution.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67853858/flutter-how-to-control-a-pageview-by-getxcontroller/67856015#67856015

Answer (score 0):

try to look at this it might help you the one i answered back

[Flutter: How to control a PageView by GetxController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67853858/flutter-how-to-control-a-pageview-by-getxcontroller/67856015#67856015)